# Number of ways to obtain a straight flush?

Tags: combinatorics

Straight flush: 5 consecutive ranks, all cards of the same suit.

My answer is $(13-5+1) \times 4 = 36$ but the answer my professor gives is 40. Where I got wrong?

Comment: It seems that, in poker, $10,12,13,14,A$ also gives straight flush. ("royal flush"). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands#Straight_flush. So your professor may be right but then this is not a mathematical problem, really...

Comment: Thank you @user8734617, now the answer makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The first rank can be anything between $1-10$:
$$(\text{A},2,3,4,5)$$
$$(2,3,4,5,6)$$
$$\dots$$
$$(10,\text{J},\text{Q},\text{K},\text{A})$$
 Thus there are $40$ straight flushes. As noted by user8734617, $(10,\text{J},\text{Q},\text{K},\text{A})$ is also considered as a "royal flush".